# PHP select menu starting from current year

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I am using Bootstrap and PHP. The formmail works however the last option value (the year) in the code below prints the value from the previous option value (the day). I am not sure where I went wrong.

Values post to email:
Serve by Month.: 1
Serve by Day.: 2
Serve by Year.: 2 (year is the same as day)

```
<select id="Serve_by_Month" name="Serve_by_Month" required>
<option value="">Month*</option>
<?for($xx=1;$xx<13;$xx++){?>

<option value="<?=$xx?>"<?if($xx==$exp_mo)echo " selected";?>> 
<?=sprintf("%02d",$xx)?>
</option>
<?}?>
</select>
<br class="hidden-lg">
<select id="Serve_by_Day" name="Serve_by_Day" required>
<option value="">Day*</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select id="Serve_by_Year" name="Serve_by_Year" required>
<option value="">Year*</option>
<?
$year = date("Y");
$yearto = date("Y")+10;
while ($year <= $yearto)
{
echo "<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>";
$year++;
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: what is your php code after submit?

Comment: the code above has an undefined variable `exp_mo` - but seems to work

Comment: In the dropdown, your code is printing year till 2027. In case you are concerned about the values Posted to the Action Script, then we need to see the Action Script as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I did any php, but could this issue have something to do with date("Y") returning a string and not an int?

Try changing the $year assignment to

```
$year = intval(date("Y"));
$yearto = $year+10;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code you mentioned produces the exact same results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should solve your problem

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit-form'])){
        $selectedMonth = $_POST['Serve_by_Month']; //This will give you the month
        $selectedDay = $_POST['Serve_by_Day']; //This will give you the day
        $selectedYear = $_POST['Serve_by_Year']; //This will give you the year
        echo 'date: '.$selectedMonth.'-'.$selectedDay.'-'.$selectedYear;
        echo '<br>';
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <select id="Serve_by_Month" name="Serve_by_Month" required>
        <option value="">Month*</option>
        <?php 
            for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){
                $selected = $i==$exp_mo ? 'selected' : '';
            ?>
            <option value="<?=$i?>" <?=$selected?>>
                <?=sprintf("%02d",$i)?>
            </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <br class="hidden-lg">

    <select id="Serve_by_Day" name="Serve_by_Day" required>
        <option value="">Day*</option>
        <?php
            for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++){ ?>
                <option value="<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></option>              
            <?php }
        ?>
    </select>

    <select id="Serve_by_Year" name="Serve_by_Year" required>
        <option value="">Year*</option>
        <?php
        for($i = date('Y'); $i <= date('Y')+10; $i++){?>
            <option value="<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></option>
        <?php }
        ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit-form"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @RamRaider good call. Totally missed that. With that said, after fixing this, I still have the same issue. Will implement a few other ideas mentioned here.

Comment: @ControlZ it worked for me. Doesn't it echo the date correctly after submit?